# How to mock Jodatime DateTime with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jodatime

I am currently trying to mock a DateTime object so that I can intercept it and make it create a constant (predetermined) DateTime object everytime a new DateTime object is made in my test.

In my actual method, I am creating the DateTime object like this:

`DateTime start = new LocalDateTime().toDateTime().minusHours(1)`

`DateTime end = new LocalDateTime().toDateTime()`

Right now, I am mocking the LocalDateTime object and DateTime object, but am not sure how to carry on:

```
@Mock
DateTime dt;

@Mock
LocalDateTime ldt;

@Test
public void test() {
    when(new DateTime()).thenReturn( ???? ); // Stuck here.
    when(new LocalDateTime().toDateTime()).thenReturn(dt);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock static method calls (or constructor invocations) with Mockito; you can with Powermock, however this is probably the wrong approach.

You might want to consider using [`DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillis*` methods](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed(long)) to control Jodatime's notion of the current time. For example, you can make the time fixed. The disadvantage of this is that it is mutating global state, and thus may have unexpected effects; you also need to ensure that you reset the current millis provider after your test.

However, a better solution is to use dependency injection, so you inject *something* into the class under test which allows you to create instances of `DateTime`, e.g. a `Supplier<DateTime>`, so you invoke the non-static `supplier.get()` rather than `new DateTime()`.

Comment: Is there any way to reset it back to default after using `setCurrentMillisFixed`?

Comment: `setCurrentMillisSystem()`.